# Trouble installing my first theme from a URL on Drupal

Tags: drupal

I am a Drupal noob. I am trying to install [this](https://drupal.org/project/zen) theme from a URL. Following the example on the Drupal screen "http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/name.tar.gz" I tried entering this URL "https://drupal.org/projects/zen-7.x-5.4.tar.gz" and this URL "https://drupal.org/files/projects/zen-7.x-5.4.tar.gz" but both gave me "unable to retrieve Drupal project" errors. How do I download the packages from [here](https://drupal.org/node/2071055)?

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://drupal.org/project/zen, at the bottom under `Downloads`, click on the desired release. (http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/zen-7.x-5.4.zip)

Once downloaded, unzip de package and move the theme directory under `sites/all/themes` folder. To activate your downloaded theme you need to login to the admin interface of Drupal.

Once logged in, go to `Appearance` and click `Enable and set default` to activate your theme.